# How to determine the type of class instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

To determine the class, I can do so:

```
class A: pass    
a = A

type(A) is type #True
```

or:

```
import inspect
inspect.isclass(A)
```

But how to determine the type of class instance, not knowing the class name?

Something like this:

```
isinstance(a, a.__class__.__name__)
#TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

I found one solution, but it does not work with Python 3x

```
import types

class A: pass
a = A()

print(type(a) == types.InstanceType)
#AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'InstanceType'
```

**Solution:**

```
if '__dict__' in dir(a) and type(a) is not type:
```

Comment: Are you asking about how to determine whether an object is a class or an instance of a class?

Comment: InstanceType is old-style classes, which don't exist in 3.x.

Comment: @grifaton, I want to distinguish class from instance

Comment: Both classes and instances are equally valid objects, and both have a meaningful type. It does not make a lot of sense to distinguish between "classes and instances" - a class is an instance too, namely an instance of a metaclass. And metaclasses are classes too, and themselves instances of some class (`type(type) is type`). Why do you think you need this?

Comment: What do you need this for? There's probably a better solution than what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Opsa: Your solution under "solution" makes no sense and won't work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`type(a)` is the type of the instance, i.e., its class.  `a.__class__` is also a reference to the instance's class, but you should use `type(a)`.

`types.InstanceType` is only for old-style classes in versions of Python pre-3.0, where all instances had the same type. You should be using new-style classes (derived from `object`) in 2.x. In Python 3.0, all classes are new-style classes.

Comment: type(a) only works for new-style classes! If you're using old-style classes -- see if you can change them to new-style. Otherwise use a.__class__ which does work with old-style too. @kindall's answer alludes to this already but I thought I'd unpack this gotcha a bit more for people.

Answer (score 24):

Your question is a bit unclear. You want to determine the "type of class instance". This can mean two things. Either you want to determine is an instance is an instance of a specific class. You can do that like so:

```
>>> isinstance(a, A)
True
```

You can also get the class with the `type()` call, but that is generally not very useful:

```
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.A'>
```

But the tests you show doesn't check this. Instead they check what type the *class* is. But Python 3 only has one type of class. Python 2 and both "old-style" and "new-style" classes, but Python 3 only have new-style classes, so there is no need to make this kind of check in Python 3.

You can also use metaclasses. In that case you can find the metaclass by checking the class's `__class__`:

```
>>> from abc import ABCMeta
>>> class B(metaclass=ABCMeta): pass
>>> type(B)
<class 'abc.ABCMeta'>
```

From your comments, however, it seems that you want to determine if an object is an instance or not. You would have gotten better answers if you asked that instead...

Anyway, to do that you use `inspect.isclass`:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.isclass(a)
False
>>> inspect.isclass(A)
True
```

This is because everything is an instance:

```
>>> isinstance(type, type)
True
```

But not everything is a class.

Answer (score 1):

It's because that the old-style class instances are all InstanceType, in Python 3.x there is only new-style classes, which are same as types. So a will be type A in Python 3.x. Then there is no need to include InstanceType, so it doesn't exist any more.